# How do I start my android activity on start of other applications?

Tags: android, android-activity

For example, if I start any app on the phone like Chrome or Calculator, my app's screen should be displayed before that app's does. I tried searching for it but I had no luck :/
Thank you.

Comment: I don't think that's possible because once the android system opens and application, that application alone has control of what screens to be opened.

Comment: There is this app called 'Applock' which displays itself before the activity starts..